# error with running agent from xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I thought this would be easy:

```
function assignToMeAgent() {    
    if (null != viewScope.get("rowId")) {    
        var _db: NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(datasources["server"], datasources["database"]);
        var doc: NotesDocument = _db.getDocumentByUNID(viewScope.get("rowId"));    
        if (null != doc) {    
            var agent: NotesAgent = _db.getAgent("ABC");
            if (agent != null) {    
                agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I can an error at line:

agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc);

If I include print statements I see that the document is found in the database and that the agent is found.

The error message I get is as followed:

[0B5C:000D-127C] 2018-01-22 12:36:48   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in E:/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/log
[0B5C:000D-127C] 2018-01-22 12:39:36   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression

Answer (score 1):

found the answer:
Run as Web user

Note: Domino Server-based Agent code must run in an Agent with "Run as Web user" selected on the Security tab under Properties.

in this post:

http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/passing-a-document-to-an-agent-without-saving-it-first.htm